How to get all transfer instructions from a VersionedTransaction in rust
I have a VersionedTransaction and I would like to extract all the instructions (and inner instructions) containing a transfer. The end goal would be see all the token flows from the signer wallet, before actually sending the transaction, using rust.
From the transaction I get the compiled_instructions. Then I can loop over the instructions and get the invoked program_id using the program_idx and the static_account_keys. But not sure how to proceed from here?
I wonder if the transaction is for example a swap on a program, is it possible getting all the transfer transaction without knowing the program IDL?

By just looking at a transaction, it's impossible to know all of the token flows. If the transaction contains an instruction for a swap protocol, for example, the swap program decides what token transfers to perform (based on AMM logic, other math, etc.). None of this is visible on just the transaction since it depends on program logic.
If you want to get token flows, you'll need to simulate the transaction with simulateTransaction and read the account changes afterwards, or fetch a transaction that has already been executed with getTransaction and look at the pre / post token balances.
